# How does one get an Epson Lx 300+II to work with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: printing, epson

In our office this printer works in systems those have older versions of Ubuntu 10.04. We are upgrading systems with this latest version 12.04. So we are in trouble.We are unable to take printouts in new version systems.Printer not working after upgrade to 12.04.

Comment: Has this been resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Generic IBM Compatile Dot-Matrix Printer PPD driver?

See: [Printer: Generic IBM-Compatible Dot Matrix Printer | OpenPrinting - The Linux Foundation](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Generic/Generic-IBM-Compatible_Dot_Matrix_Printer)

Comment: Yes sir, It does not support it.